# Building a d-heap from a given array of integers

Tags: java, heap

So I'm building a d heap and this is my constructor:

```
public DHeap(int[] items)
{
    currentSize = items.length;
    array = new int[(currentSize + 2) * 11 / 10];

    int i = 0;
    for(int item : items)
        array[ i++ ] = item;

    buildHeap();
}
```

So basically it's taking in an array and it needs to build it into a heap so to speak. And I'm confused about the buildHeap method. I know for a binary heap the buildHeap method is:

```
private void buildHeap()
{
    for(int i = currentSize / 2; i >= 0; i--)
        percolateDown(i);
}
```

However, I'm making a d heap (d = number of children each node has). And so I'm confused on how the buildHeap method would be set up. Would it be set up like this?

```
private void buildHeap()
{
    for(int i = currentSize / d; i >= 0; i--) // d is a global variable
        percolateDown(i);
}
```

Or would it be set up exactly like the binary heap? And just to clarify percolateDown is the same as heapifyDown, I know sometimes people use different terminology for it.

Comment: In binary heap you start from `currentSize / 2` because you don't need the leafs. The same is true for d-heap, since each level is d times bigger you need `currentSize / d`.

Answer (score 0):

The insight behind the *build-heap* algorithm is that you have to sift down all non-leaf nodes. In a full binary heap, half of the nodes are leaf nodes. You obviously can't push a leaf node down any further, so you start at the first non-leaf node, which is at n/2.

In a d-heap, the number of leaf nodes is much larger in proportion to the total size of the heap. For example, in a 4-heap with three levels there are 16 leaf nodes, and 5 non-leaf nodes. The *build-heap* method only needs to check five nodes, or `1+(n/d)`. You start at node `n/d`.

See my blog post, [The d-ary heap](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/10/05/the-d-ary-heap/), for a bit more information.